# Property 'style' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using vue and typescript, and I'm trying to modify an element style.

```
let foo = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (event.target) {
        event.target.style.opacity = 1
```

the code works, but typescript keeps giving me

```
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

any solution ?

Comment: [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) could be `Node`, `HTMLElement`, `SVGElement`, `window`, `document`, `AudioNode`, `AudioContext`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc. Not all of them have a `style` property. You need to use a type guard (`if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) { /* event.target.style works here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check if it's an element before proceeding:

```
if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
    event.target.style.opacity = 1 // ok
```